# Which Control to use in ASP.NET to Display Picture Block with full access to CSS3

Tags: asp.net

Need some expertise here.

I want to achieve the output similar to the one attached as a image. This snapshot format I was able to achieve using `<UL> & <LI>` (see code below) tags which was formed in the ASP.NET code behind on the load of page. The below was displayed in the div tag `<div id="catDisplay" class="catDisplay" runat="server"></div>`

```
            strDataString.Append("")
            strDataString.AppendLine("<ul class='categories'>")

            Do While objDataReader.Read

                intCategoryID = objDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString()
                strCategoryName = objDataReader.GetValue(1).ToString()
                strCategoryImage = objDataReader.GetValue(2).ToString()

                If Len(Trim(strCategoryImage)) = 0 Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(Trim(strCategoryImage)) = True Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Trim(strCategoryImage)) = True Then
                    strCategoryImageWithPath = "Images/noimage.png"
                Else
                    strCategoryImageWithPath = "base_Clients/" & intAccountID.ToString() & "/Category/" & strCategoryImage.ToString()
                End If

                intSortSequence = objDataReader.GetValue(3).ToString()
                intCategoryStatus = objDataReader.GetValue(4).ToString()

                If Trim(intCategoryStatus) = 0 Then
                    setCategoryStatus = "Inactive"
                End If

                strDataString.Append("<li id='li_" & i & "'>")

                strDataString.Append("<div class='liContents'>")
                strDataString.Append("<span class='catImage'><img src='" & strCategoryImageWithPath.ToString() & "' alt='" & strCategoryName.ToString() & "' width='200' height='131' /></span>")
                strDataString.Append("<span class='catContentsBar'></span>")
                strDataString.Append("<span class='catTitle' title='Category Name: " & strCategoryName.ToString() & "' >" & strCategoryName.ToString() & "</span>")
                strDataString.Append("<span class='catStatus' title='Category Status'>" & setCategoryStatus & "</span>")
                strDataString.Append("<span class='catSort' title='Category Sort Sequence is " & intSortSequence.ToString() & "' >" & intSortSequence.ToString() & "</span>")

                ' the below is for the Edit and Delete Button
                strDataString.Append("<span id='nav_" & i & "' class='navigation'>")

                strDataString.Append("<button id='btnInsert_" & i & "' type='button' class='SmallButtonWithImage' title='Add New Category' onClick='fn_CategoryManagement(1, 0)'>")
                strDataString.Append("<img src='Images/menuicons/add.png' alt='Add' hspace='2' />")
                strDataString.Append("</button>")

                strDataString.Append("<button id='btnEdit_" & i & "' type='button' class='SmallButtonWithImage' title='Edit Category: " + strCategoryName.ToString() + "' onClick='fn_CategoryManagement(2, """ & intCategoryID.ToString() & """)'>")
                strDataString.Append("<img src='Images/menuicons/edit.gif' alt='Edit' hspace='2' />")
                strDataString.Append("</button>")

                strDataString.Append("<button id='btnDelete_" & i & "' type='button' class='SmallButtonWithImage' title='Delete Category: " & strCategoryName.ToString() & "' onClick='fn_DeleteConfirm(""" & intCategoryID.ToString() & """)'>")
                strDataString.Append("<img src='Images/menuicons/delete.png' alt='Delete' hspace='2' />")
                strDataString.Append("</button>")
                strDataString.Append("</span>")

                strDataString.Append("</div>")

                strDataString.Append("</li>")

                i = i + 1
            Loop

            strDataString.AppendLine("</ul>")
```

Initially, due to time constraints, I had to opt for this. It is difficult to manage the above code. Can anyone suggest me what is the best control with some example URLs (not necessarily directly related) in ASP.NET should I use to achieve the same output with full accessibility to CSS3.

Appreciate.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest either one from below

1. ListView control, check this [Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui)
2. Repeater control
3. Inline syntax with for-each (Tough to ready and easy to modify layout)

Comment: Thanks, I am testing the ListView control, I am able to get 90% of the formatting similar to the image.